# How to send email notification for expiry of account before 5 working days

Tags: java, datetime

I made one stand alone method to send email before 5 normal days from date of password expire to respective user whose password will expire in 30 days. Now I am confused how to send email before 5 working days from password expire. Following are the logic which I made for send notification to user before 5 normal days.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");          
System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
System.out.println("Creating statement...");
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql;
sql = "select EMAIL_ID from  user_master where date_add(password_change_date, interval 25 day) < CURDATE();";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){               
 String emailId  = rs.getString("email_id");             
System.out.println("Email Id: "+emailId);
 PasswordExpiry.sendHTMLEmail( from, emailId, host, user, password, subject, body );
              } 
rs.close();
 stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

PasswordExpiry.sendHTMLEmail() method for sending mail to respective user.

Comment: Can you clarify please? 30 days before the password expires, the emails should get sent. What about the 5 days? Is it 5 working days before the password will expire in 30 days? Or is the mail sent twice? 30 days before and 5 work days before? Maybe add an example with concrete days?

Comment: @Jan: Example: if my "last_password_date" is 30 Oct 2015 so as per password policy of 30 days..its expired on 29 Nov 2015 which is on Wednesday. So I want that user will get email notification that "Your password will expire soon" before 5 working day. So in this case user will get email notification from 23 Nov 2015 i.e from Monday.

Comment: * 29 Nov 2015 which is Sunday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example I fiddled [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/126b45):

```
select expiry, dayname(expiry) as expiry_weekday, user, 

                         CASE weekday(expiry)
                           WHEN 0 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -7 DAY) -- MON -> MON
                           WHEN 1 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -7 DAY) -- TUE -> TUE
                           WHEN 2 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -7 DAY) -- WED -> WED
                           WHEN 3 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -7 DAY) -- THU -> THU
                           WHEN 4 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -7 DAY) -- FRI -> FRI
                           WHEN 5 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -8 DAY) -- SAT -> FRI
                           WHEN 6 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -9 DAY) -- SUN -> FRI
                         END
                          as notification_date,

                         dayname(CASE weekday(expiry)
                                 WHEN 0 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -7 DAY) -- MON -> MON
                                 WHEN 1 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -7 DAY) -- TUE -> TUE
                                 WHEN 2 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -7 DAY) -- WED -> WED
                                 WHEN 3 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -7 DAY) -- THU -> THU
                                 WHEN 4 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -7 DAY) -- FRI -> FRI
                                 WHEN 5 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -8 DAY) -- SAT -> FRI
                                 WHEN 6 THEN date_add(expiry,INTERVAL -9 DAY) -- SUN -> FRI
                                 END
                                ) as notification_weekday
FROM pwd_expiry ;
```

This calulates the day of week for password expiry and the day-of-week for notification based on that. Not sure if I have your timings right yet - but you should be able to work from there. Basically it would create a different day offset for notification based on day-of-week for expiration. Once you pull that CASE WHEN into your WHERE condition, you should be good to go. Returning not only the user name but also the actual expiration date might be a good idea to include this innotification email.

As the fiddle dies - this would be input:

```
+-------+---------------------+
| user  | expiry              |
+-------+---------------------+
| jan   | 2015-12-25 00:00:00 |
| xplod | 2015-12-31 00:00:00 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

and that will be output:

```
+---------------------+----------------+-------+---------------------+----------------------+
| expiry              | expiry_weekday | user  | notification_date   | notification_weekday |
+---------------------+----------------+-------+---------------------+----------------------+
| 2015-12-25 00:00:00 | Friday         | jan   | 2015-12-18 00:00:00 | Friday               |
| 2015-12-31 00:00:00 | Thursday       | xplod | 2015-12-24 00:00:00 | Thursday             |
+---------------------+----------------+-------+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: thanks for your input!! I can do some more analysis base on this for my requirement. but definitely I can use notification_date for sending password to respective users. Thanks Jan!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this generaic method to find working days between two days:

```
public static int getWorkingDaysBetweenTwoDates(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
        Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        startCal.setTime(startDate);
        Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        endCal.setTime(endDate);
        int workDays = 0;
        //Return 0 if start and end are the same
        if (startCal.getTimeInMillis() == endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {
            return 0;
        }
    if (startCal.getTimeInMillis() > endCal.getTimeInMillis()) {
        startCal.setTime(endDate);
        endCal.setTime(startDate);
    }
    do {
        //excluding start date
        startCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        if (startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            ++workDays;
        }
    } while (startCal.getTimeInMillis() < endCal.getTimeInMillis()); //excluding end date
    return workDays;
```

}

As per your requirement, This method will return you number of days remaining password to be expired. If this > 5 you can send email. or tell password is valid till Number of days in email like windows

Comment: thanks for your input. But please check one example which I mention for Jan. I don't want to calculate working days. between two dates.